# Menú expandible con opciones que aparecen tras un intervalo de tiempo

Tags: javascript, css

Quiero saber cómo puedo hacer un menú que tenga un tamaño chico a primera vista, con un enlace visible en el centro, y que al pasar el cursor del ratón por encima del menú, éste se expanda hacia los lados y le aparezcan dos enlaces más adentro suyo, uno de cada lado. Ya probé con JavaScript y CSS y no pude lograrlo. No sé jQuery, así que agradecería que usen JavaScript nativo en todo caso.

Mi idea fue usar un `div` y tres elementos afuera del `div` (uno en el centro del `div` visible desde el principio y los de los lados ocultos), todo con posición absoluta, y transiciones con CSS para que se expanda el `div`, que es el "fondo" del menú, y después, cuando el `div` se expandiera lo suficiente haría visibles los elementos de los lados que pude, pero no puedo hacerlos invisibles otra vez a tiempo cuando el cursor sale del `div`.

```
                                    Normal:
                           _______________________
                          |                       |
                          |          <a>          |
                          |_______________________|

                                   MouseOver:
         ____________________________________________________________
        |                                                            |
        |      <a>                   <a>                    <a>      |
        |____________________________________________________________|

                                   MouseOut:
                           _______________________
                          |                       |
                          |          <a>          |
                          |_______________________|
```

Debería pasar como en el gráfico, pero con `0.2s` de `transition` en CSS, que es lo que tarda en expandirse y contraerse. Los enlaces de los lados deberían aparecer justo después de que se termina de expandir el `div`, y desaparecer justo luego de que sale el cursor del mismo.

CSS del `div`:

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width:20%;
    left:40.25%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0.75%;
    border-radius:30px;
    background: url('imagenes/banner.jpg') center center;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px 2px #EEE;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Los enlaces, solamente tienen coordenadas y estilos de texto, así que no considero relevante poner su CSS acá. Lo que sí, los de los lados tienen `visibility: hidden` de manera predeterminada.

- El `id` del `div` es `menu`.
- El enlace del medio es `Everant`, el que siempre es visible.
- Los enlaces invisibles son `teoria` y `practica`, que aparecen cuando se expande el menú.

Javascript:

```js
var overText = false;

function gbId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function Enlarge() {
    var menu = gbId('menu');
    var teoria = gbId('teoria');
    var practica = gbId('practica');
    var i = 0;
    var t = null;

    menu.style.width = '60%';
    menu.style.left = '20%';

    t = setInterval(function(){
        if (i == 20) {
            teoria.style.visibility = 'visible';
            practica.style.visibility = 'visible';
            t = clearInterval(t);
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }, 1);
}
function Minimize() {
    var menu = gbId('menu');
    var teoria = gbId('teoria');
    var practica = gbId('practica');

    menu.style.width = '20%';
    menu.style.left = '40.25%';
    teoria.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    practica.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function Lock() {
    var menu = gbId('menu');
    menu.style.width = '60%';
    menu.style.left = '20%';
    teoria.style.visibility = 'visible';
    practica.style.visibility = 'visible';
    overText = true;
}
function Unlock() {
    if (overText) {
        var menu = gbId('menu');
        menu.style.width = '20%';
        menu.style.left = '40.25%';
        teoria.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        practica.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        overText = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esto lo podrías realizar solamente con CSS con una lista (`ul`) y en cada uno de los elementos (`li`) darles la propiedad para que actúen como `inline-block`. De esta manera, los pondrás a todos en una misma línea.

Después puedes utilizar una clase para que se muestren o no con `visibility: hidden;` o `visibility: visible` dependiendo de si estás pasando por encima del link principal o no.

Por último, como todavía no existen selectores para mostrar todos los elementos anteriores a otro (por ejemplo si pasamos por el link principal podremos mostrar el link de la derecha mediante selectores pero no el de la izquierda), lo que puedes realizar es poner el link principal el primero y cambiar el orden con respecto a los otros dos. Para ello puedes usar flexbox.

Le he puesto color a los links para que se vea mejor.

Ejemplo:

```css
/* Hacemos que la lista actúe como flexbox */
ul{
  display: flex;
}

/* Cambiamos el orden a los elementos */
#primerLink{
  order: 1;
}

#principal{
  order: 2;
}

#segundoLink{
  order: 3;
}

/* Indicamos que cada uno de los elementos sea inline-block */
.menu{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

/* Escondemos los links de los lados */
.escondido{
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Mostramos los links de los lados cuando pasamos por encima del principal */
#principal:hover ~ li{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="principal" class="menu"><a href="#">Principal</a></li>
  <li id="primerLink" class="menu escondido"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
  <li id="segundoLink" class="menu escondido"><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Quiero comentar un código nuevo que hice a partir del tuyo y no me deja porque es muy largo, cómo hago?

Comment: @Marz Puedes crear un jsfiddle, guardarlo y poner el link en un comentario. Si le das al Save tendrás que copiar el link que te aparece en la url. La página de la que te hablo es esta: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t978pzfL/ ahí está. Igual ahora que lo veo, en una pantalla con medidas distintas a la mía el gráfico no se ve bien >.< qué difícil que es manejar bien las proporciones. Lo único que me pasa, aparte de lo de las proporciones, es que el primer link no permanece visible al pasarle el cursor encima al segundo, y seguramente es porque está antes que él en el html, pero no sé cómo hacer para seleccionarlo, intenté con js pero no me salió bien.

Comment: @Marz Si no entiendo mal lo que quieres hacer es que al pasar por el segundo link (el de la derecha) se mantenga también el primero visible, ¿no?

Comment: Ajam, y también mantener las proporciones del menú sin importar las medidas de la pantalla.

Comment: @Marz Luego le echo un vistazo.

Comment: Oka, gracias n.n Yo de mientras avanzo con otras cosas

Answer (score 2):

Tengo algo que te puede servir, pero tienes que mejorarlo porque solamente se desocultan los elementos siguientes al que haces hover, incluyéndolo. Te recomiendo el uso de jQuery para esto. De todas formas, esto te puede servir como punto de partida y tiene incluida una pequeña transición.

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: -moz-max-content;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.menu:not(:first-child) {
    visivility: none;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.menu:hover, .menu:hover ~ .menu {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu"> Opcion A </li>
    <li class="menu"> Opcion B </li>
    <li class="menu"> Opcion C </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo de la opacidad me dio la idea de usarla para esto, da un efecto muy bonito n.n En cuanto a lo otro, estoy usando lo que me comentó Error404